# How can I use my svg icons with q-btn-toggle

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm using quasar in my project and I want to use my svg icons with q-btn-toggle, [it says](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/button-toggle#design) that it is enough to give the direct path here, but my svg icon does not come. Below I leave my code sample.

```
template(lang="pug")
          q-btn-toggle.my-custom-toggle(v-model="secondModel" color="white" text-color="primary" :options="toggleOption" size="sm")
```

Data

```
      toggleOption: [
    { label: 'Table', value: 'table', slot: 'one', icon: require('@/assets/svg/toggle/Table.svg') },
    { label: 'Calendar', value: 'calendar', slot: 'two', icon: '@/assets/svg/toggle/Table.svg' }
  ],
  secondModel: 'table'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says the following about specifying custom icons:

> `icon : String`
>
> ###### Description
>
> Icon of option button; Use this prop and/or 'label', but at least one is required
>
> ###### Examples
>
> - `map`
> - `ion-add`
> - `img:https://cdn.quasar.dev/logo-v2/svg/logo.svg`
> - `img:path/to/some_image.png`

The path to the icon image must be prepended with `img:`. Furthermore, the Quasar documentation discusses referencing files in the `assets` [here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/handling-assets#asset-resolving-rules) and says:

> Quasar provides the `assets` alias out of the box, so it is recommended that you use it like this: `<img src="~assets/logo.png">`. Notice `~` in front of ‘assets’.

Putting all of this together, your option definitions should probably look something like:

```js
[
  {
    label: 'Calendar',
    value: 'calendar',
    slot: 'two',
    icon: 'img:~assets/svg/toggle/Table.svg'
  },
  . . .
]
```

Here is a working example showing a custom icon that references an image at a URL: https://codepen.io/euphemism/pen/PoQLqRe?editors=101